# Netbeans @JoinColoumns error with auto generated entity class

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jakarta-ee, jpa

I've creating entities from a data-source using Netbeans 7.4.

And I have an error which arises with all entities which have a composite primary key. The error can be seen below.

I have searched this problem on stack-overflow and its is usually because people have not defined the join columns. but I have this done. I'm also unsure how there is errors in code generated by netbeans.

Here is an image of my MySQL database which I forward engineered to create these entitys:

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

[image]

Here is the only the relevant code

**Absence entity:**

```
public class Absence implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EmbeddedId
    protected AbsencePK absencePK;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "idAbsence")
    private int idAbsence;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "Date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date date;
    @Size(max = 35)
    @Column(name = "type")
    private String type;
    @Lob
    @Size(max = 65535)
    @Column(name = "remark")
    private String remark;
    @JoinColumn(name = "TimeTable_Period", referencedColumnName = "Period", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Timetable timetable;
    @JoinColumn(name = "Student_idStudent", referencedColumnName = "idStudent", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Student student;
    @JoinColumn(name = "Class_idClass", referencedColumnName = "idClass", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Class class1;
```

**AbsencePK entity:**

```
@Embeddable
public class AbsencePK implements Serializable {
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "Class_idClass")
    private int classidClass;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "Student_idStudent")
    private int studentidStudent;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "TimeTable_Period")
    private int timeTablePeriod;

    public AbsencePK() {
    }

    public AbsencePK(int classidClass, int studentidStudent, int timeTablePeriod) {
        this.classidClass = classidClass;
        this.studentidStudent = studentidStudent;
        this.timeTablePeriod = timeTablePeriod;
    }
```

**Error:**

Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-7220] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): 
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The @JoinColumns on the annotated element [field timetable] from the entity class [class com.fyp.simstest.Absence] is incomplete. 
When the source entity class uses a composite primary key, a @JoinColumn must be specified for each join column using the @JoinColumns. 
Both the name and the referencedColumnName elements must be specified in each such @JoinColumn.
at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.incompleteJoinColumnsSpecified(ValidationException.java:1847)

**EDIT**

**TimeTable**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "timetable")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Timetable.findAll", query = "SELECT t FROM Timetable t"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Timetable.findByPeriod", query = "SELECT t FROM Timetable t WHERE t.timetablePK.period = :period"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Timetable.findByDay", query = "SELECT t FROM Timetable t WHERE t.timetablePK.day = :day"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Timetable.findByClassidClass", query = "SELECT t FROM Timetable t WHERE t.timetablePK.classidClass = :classidClass")})
public class Timetable implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EmbeddedId
    protected TimetablePK timetablePK;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "timetable")
    private Collection<Absence> absenceCollection;
    @JoinColumn(name = "Class_idClass", referencedColumnName = "idClass", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Class class1;

    public Timetable() {
    }

    public Timetable(TimetablePK timetablePK) {
        this.timetablePK = timetablePK;
    }
```

**TimetablePK**

```
Embeddable
public class TimetablePK implements Serializable {
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "Period")
    private int period;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "Day")
    private String day;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "Class_idClass")
    private int classidClass;

    public TimetablePK() {
    }

    public TimetablePK(int period, String day, int classidClass) {
        this.period = period;
        this.day = day;
        this.classidClass = classidClass;
    }
```

**EDIT TWO**

Comment: @Brawn It is an epic fail when you use @ Basic with false and @ NotNull on one column. You can make it by doing this @Column(name=" ",nullable = false)

Comment: actually it's not fail. @NotNull can be used by `bean validation` for instance, while the `nullable = false` cannot. Athough you can skip the `Basic` and convert the `optional=false` to `nullable=false` in the `Column` annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your diagram indicates the `TimeTable` table has a primary key composed of three columns (`Period`, `Day`, and `Class_idClass`). You will need to add an annotation to `Absence.timeTable` that looks something like this:

```
public class Absence implements Serializable {
    ...
    @JoinColumns[
        @JoinColumn(name = "TimeTable_Period", referencedColumnName = "Period", ...),
        @JoinColumn(name = "????", referencedColumnName = "Day", ...),
        @JoinColumn(name = "Class_idClass", referencedColumnName = "Class_idClass", ...)
    ]
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private TimeTable timeTable;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have updated my question with my timetable and timetablePK files, you said in your answer I need to add an annotation to the Absence.timetable which entity is this ? @vosburgh

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is.... The `@JoinColumns` annotation I describe should be applied to the `timeTable` field in the `Absense` class. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "TimeTable_Period", referencedColumnName = "Period")
private Timetable timetable;
```

You have referenced to the column `Period` at your `Timetable` entity. But in the `Timetable.java` I don't see any field that is mapped with your `Period` column of your table.

For example:

```
@Id // as its the primary key!
@Column(name="Period")
private Long period
```

This should be same for other referenced entities those you have used with your `@ManyToOne` mapping.